# Cannot get functions to work in Corona SDK (With TabButton)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am completely new to Corona SDK and I am just looking at the example projects just to see how things work. I am looking at the TAB example however I have a problem.

I have a page like so (this is page2)

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called when the scene's view does not exist.
    -- 
    -- INSERT code here to initialize the scene
    -- e.g. add display objects to 'sceneGroup', add touch listeners, etc.

    -- create a white background to fill screen (things go in here like pictures etc)
    local bg = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    bg.anchorX = 0
    bg.anchorY = 0
    bg:setFillColor( 0 )    -- white

    -- this will create the thing that you drag (the function is after)
    local tracker = display.newRect( 568, 340, 50, 50 )
    tracker:setFillColor( 1 )

    -- all objects must be added to group (e.g. self.view)
    sceneGroup:insert( bg )
    sceneGroup:insert( tracker )
end

function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if phase == "will" then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen and is about to move on screen
    elseif phase == "did" then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen
        -- 
        -- INSERT code here to make the scene come alive
        -- e.g. start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
    end 
end

function scene:hide( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if event.phase == "will" then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen and is about to move off screen
        --
        -- INSERT code here to pause the scene
        -- e.g. stop timers, stop animation, unload sounds, etc.)
    elseif phase == "did" then
        -- Called when the scene is now off screen
    end
end

function scene:destroy( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (sceneGroup)
    -- 
    -- INSERT code here to cleanup the scene
    -- e.g. remove display objects, remove touch listeners, save state, etc.
end

function tracker:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        self.markX = self.x --stores x location
        self.markY = self.y --stores y location
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY
        self.x, self.y = x, y -- moves the object from things above
    end
end



---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
tracker:addEventListneer( "touch", tracker)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Anyway to simplify things the changes I have done are:

```
local tracker = display.newRect( 568, 340, 50, 50 )
tracker:setFillColor( 1 )
```

This will create a new box which I am trying to make so you can drag it around the screen (I have used this function):

```
function tracker:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        self.markX = self.x --stores x location
        self.markY = self.y --stores y location
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY
        self.x, self.y = x, y -- moves the object from things above
    end
end
```

So overall it creates a box and I am trying to add a function to it so that you can drag it around the screen. However it does not work and gives me an error saying that `tracker` on that start of the function line `function tracker:touch( event )` is wrong? Any help, because I think that this is in the wrong place.

P.S I also have a `tracker:addEventListneer( "touch", tracker)` listener.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `local tracker` as a local variable inside your `scene:create` function. This means this variable will only be available within the scope of said function.

You need to move the function `tracker:touch(event)` inside the `scene:create` function for the tracker to be reachable.

And you need to move the listener to the bottom of the `scene:create` function.

Comment: Oh right, thanks. However, it has not worked because I put the `tracker:addEventListneer( "touch", tracker)` inside the `scene:create` but it still gives me an error about that? (I have also added `return true` at the bottom of my `scene:create`).

Comment: You need to link the error. All errors explain what the problem is, link and we can tell the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I have fixed it. I should always check my spelling xD (I spelled the `tracker:addEventListener( "touch", tracker)` wrong). Such a noob mistake. Thanks for the help guys.